# AngularJS storing array of objects in a cookie

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I have an array of objects stored in the scope variable. The issue with that is when the user refreshes the page, it does not persist that data, so I am considering using cookies.

The variable $scope.Users stores an array of user objects and I am using the following code to get that data into a cookie:

```
 if ($cookies.getObject('user_data') === '' || $cookies.getObject('user_data') === undefined)                            
      $cookies.putObject('user_data',$scope.Users);
```

Which does not display any data is I use

> console.log($cookies.getObject('user_data'))

and I am not getting anything back, so it seems that putObject does not save the data. What could be wrong here? Could the size of the cookie exceed the limit?

Previously I used the following to retrieve that data from my html page:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="User in Users">
    <td>{{User.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{User.ID}}</td>
    <td>{{User.DOB}}</td>
    <td>{{User.Status}}</td>
  </tr>
```

My question is how to I retrieve the array from cookies and display its contents? Also is there a better way to persist an array of objects through refresh? Would service work better?

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code.

```
var obj = {"Name": name,  "ID": id,  "DOB": dob,  "Status": status};
$scope.Users.push(obj);
$cookies.put('user_data', JSON.stringify($scope.Users));
var s = $cookies.get('user_data');
$scope.Users= JSON.parse(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you inject **`ngCookies`** as a dependency to the module,

```
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
```

You can do this in controller,

**To set data**

```
$cookies.user_data =  $scope.users;
```

**To retrieve data**

```
 $scope.Users= $cookies.user_data;
```

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="User in Users">
    <td>{{User.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{User.ID}}</td>
    <td>{{User.DOB}}</td>
    <td>{{User.Status}}</td>
</tr>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/dokob6dv/2/)**

Comment: `$cookies.put` did not work for me when dealing with objects... Also I started using cookies because $scope.users gets cleared out every time user refreshes the page, so I need more persistent data storage

Comment: @ElenaDBA Check the demo, also your angular version should be above 1.4

Comment: I use angular 1.5.8

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your scenario without issues. What version of $cookies are you using? It should match your angular version.

As for persisting data, the only other option I can think of would be to save it to a server. A service wouldn't work as the refresh would clear it out too.